# Parse XML using pugixml

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

I am trying to fetch, internet time using a web service, which provides me an xml. Now, I am trying to parse the xml file using pugixml. The XML returned

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<timezone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.earthtools.org/timezone.xsd">
  <version>1.0</version>
  <location>
    <latitude>22.5667</latitude>
    <longitude>88.3667</longitude>
  </location>
  <offset>5.5</offset>
  <suffix>E*</suffix>
  <localtime>20 Jul 2014 14:48:10</localtime>
  <isotime>2014-07-20 14:48:10 +0530</isotime>
  <utctime>2014-07-20 09:18:10</utctime>
  <dst>Unknown</dst>
</timezone>
```

The way I am trying to parse it.

```
pugi::xml_document doc;
    if (!doc.load_file("time.xml")) return -1;

    pugi::xml_node tools = doc.child("timezone").child("localtime");

    //[code_traverse_iter
    for (pugi::xml_node_iterator it = tools.begin(); it != tools.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << "Tool:";

        for (pugi::xml_attribute_iterator ait = it->attributes_begin(); ait != it->attributes_end(); ++ait)
        {
            std::cout << " " << ait->name() << "=" << ait->value();
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
```

I need fetch the value of this node

```
<localtime>20 Jul 2014 14:48:10</localtime>
```

Please help me get through this.

P.S: The web-service I am using can be found http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm, hope it helps someone.

I know I can do a simple file operation to fetch the data as the xml is not that long, but still I would like to use the parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const char* localtime = doc.child("timezone").child("localtime").text().get();
```

or

```
const char* localtime = doc.child("timezone").child_value("localtime");
```